# How to store large, multi-line text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What would be the best way to store a large amount of text in a Database? I would expect about 2500 words and since on average each word in English is around 6 characters, I expect over 15000 characters. This text may be non-English so I guess I would need Unicode to support everything.

This text needs to be inserted, retrieved, and also searched by keywords.

Maxwell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as the datatype for that particular column in question. Also, I would suggest you have a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on that column since you said that column will also include searching by keywords.

Comment: What is the maximum length of `nvarchar`?

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN, see answer, I mentioned `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and per MSDN it can can 2Billion characters which is pretty huge.

Comment: NVM, found it: `Max. capacity is 2 gigabytes of space - so you're looking at just over 1 billion 2-byte characters that will fit into a NVARCHAR(MAX) field.`

Comment: Along with this text, I need to store a title (`nvarchar(200)`) and a `bit`. Is there any reason to put the body in another table?

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN, you should use different columns for all of that and not sue if I have understood completely.

Comment: Obviously they should be different columns. I am asking if there is any benefit in putting this long text column in a separate table from everything else.

Comment: @MDTech.us_MAN, Ohh!!! NO, you can have that column in the same table as well. Not sure why you want to have it in a separate table altogether.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

You can store..

```
1 billion, 73 million, 741 thousand and 823 characters
```

Answer (score 2):

If you will insert non-english characters you have to use `NVARCHAR`, and also when inserting the data you have to prefix it with an `N` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp( description NVARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (N'Добро...')
```